# Testing 2 web applications that interact with each other

Tags: spring, junit, jms, integration-testing, activemq-classic

We are developing 2 different web applications (WARS).
Both use the same message bus (ActiveMQ - jms).

We would like to preform tests that triggers one action on a webapp#1 , that action should induce message throwing that will be consumed on webapp#2 and mutate the DB.

How can we test this end to end scenario??

We would like to have an automated test for that, and would like to avoid manual testing as much as possible.

We are using junit with springframework, and already have tons of junit that are being preformed daily, but non of them so far involved the usage of the message bus. it appear that this scenarion is a whole different story to automate.

***Are there any possibilities to test this scenario with automated script (spring \ junit \ other)?***

Answer (score 0):

A JUnit test could certainly this integration test sequence:

1. send a HTTP request to webapp#1 to trigger, using [HTTPUrlConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for example
2. run a SQL command (using JDBC) to detect wether the database contains the expected value

In the test setup, the database needs to be initialized (rest) so that the second step does not give a false-positive result